# How does compiler knows what is the type of a delegate?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's say I have a multithreading console application:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method() started");

        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Counter = {i}");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Method() finished");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Started");           
        var task = new Task(Method);
        task.Start();

        for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main finished");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

My question is how does compiler knows which delegate to use inside ..= new Task(..)?
I mean how compiler replace this stroke

```
 var task = new Task(Method);
```

with this

```
  var action = new Action(Method);
        var task = new Task(action);
```

Comment: The constructor of `Task` says it takes an `Action` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for the Action accepts a void method

```
new Action(someVoidMethod);
```

The compiler actually generated this code:

```
Task task = new Task(new Action(Program.Method));
```

Since you pass a void method with no parameters, the compiler can convert it into `Action`.